# Is pthread_kill() dangerous to use?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, winapi, pthreads

I have read that `TerminateThread()` in WinAPI is dangerous to use.

Is `pthread_kill()` in Linux also dangerous to use?

---

**Edit:** Sorry I meant `pthread_kill()` and not `pthread_exit()`.

Comment: [`TerminateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`pthread_exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html) do *different things*. Perhaps you think about [`pthread_kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_kill.html)?

Comment: The [man page is very illuminating](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html).

Comment: Why would you think that?  They're completely different.

Comment: As for *why* `TerminateThread` and `pthread_kill` might be "dangerous", think about if the threads have allocated lots of resources, and then they are simply killed without a chance to clean up after themselves? Or what if they are halfway through writing a file, what happens to that file?

Comment: Perhaps you should try to learn *why* `TerminateThread()` is dangerous...

Comment: With `TerminateThread` you can terminate _another_ thread. With `pthread_exit` you can only terminate your own thread (the calling thread).

Answer (score 1):

To quote Sir Humphrey Appleby, the answer is "yes, and no".

In and of itself calling pthread_exit() is not dangerous and is called implicitly when your thread exits its method. However, there are a few "gotchas" if you call it manually.

1. All cleanup handlers are called when this is called. So if you call this method, then access some memory that the cleanup handlers have cleaned up, you get a memory error.
2. Similarly, after this is called, any local and thread-local variables for the thread become invalid. So if a reference is made to them you can get a memory error.
3. If this has already been called for the thread (implicitly or explicitly) calling it again has an undefined behaviour, and
4. If this is the last thread in your process, this will cause the process to exit.

If you are careful of the above (i.e. if you are careful to not reference anything about the thread after you have called pthread_exit) then it is safe to call call manually. However, if you are using C++ instead of C I would highly recommend using the std::thread class rather than doing it manually. It is easier to read, involves less code, and ensures that you are not breaking any of the above.

For more information type "man pthread_exit" which will essentially tell you the above.

Comment: Looks like you mixed up pthread_kill and pthread_exit. _exit terminates the calling, while _kill sends signal to another thread

Comment: No, I just double checked and "man pthread_exit" confirms everything I said above. Perhaps the questioner meant "pthread_kill" but I chose to answer the question that was asked rather than guessing if that is what they meant to ask.

Comment: If the original question were to be modified to ask if pthread_kill is dangerous, then the unequivocal answer is "yes". Sending the thread a signal has all the potential security risks (in particular potential timing problems) that exist in sending signals to processes. In addition note that pthread_kill does not stop the thread - it just sends a signal to it.

Comment: Aw, my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: That is technically true - pthread_exit is no different than the thread function reaching its return, however it is harder to trigger the "gotchas" in the latter case.

Comment: Once again my answer is "yes, and no". If you are reasonably careful in what you are doing, pthread_exit is not dangerous.

Comment: The way you would trigger #3 is by calling pthread_exit in a cancellation handler. But I'll admit I've never tried such a thing - the inclusion of #3 in my warnings comes strictly from the man page.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has now been changed, I will write a new answer. My answer still remains "yes and no" but the reasons have changed.

pthread_kill is somewhat dangerous in that it shares the potential timing risks that is inherent in all signal handling systems. In addition there are complexities in dealing with it, specifically you have to setup a signal handler within the thread. However one could argue that it is less dangerous than the Windows function you mention. Here is why:

The Windows function essentially stops the thread, possibly bypassing the proper cleanup. It is intended as a last resort option. pthread_kill, on the other hand, does not terminate the thread at all.  It simply sends a signal to the thread that the thread can respond to.

In order for this to do something you need to have registered in the thread what signals you want it to handle. If your goal is to use pthread_kill to terminate the thread, you can use this by having your signal handler set a flag that the thread can access, and having the thread check the flag and exit when it gets set. You may be able to call pthread_exit from the signal handler (I've never tried that) but it strikes me as being a bad idea since the signal comes asynchronously, and your thread is not guaranteed to still be running. The flag option I mention solves this provided that the flag is not local to the thread, allowing the signal handler to set it even if the target thread has already exited. Of course if you are doing this, you don't really need pthread_kill at all, as you can simply have your main thread set the flag at the appropriate time.

There is another option for stopping another thread - the pthread_cancel method. This method will place a cancel request on the target thread and, if the thread has been configured to be cancellable (you generally do this in the pthread_create, but you can also do it after the fact), then the next time the thread reaches a potential cancellation point (specified by pthread_testcancel but also automatically handled by many system routines such as the IO calls), it will exit. This is also safer than what Windows does as it is not violently stopping the thread - it only stops at well defined points. But it is more work than the Windows version as you have to configure the thread properly.

The Wikipedia page for "posix threads" describes some of this (but not much), but it has a pretty good "See also" and "References" section that will give you more details.

Comment: I should also note that dealing with pthread_cancel is also not trivial, but that is another discussion.